# Putting different ggplots next to each other, while keeping a common facet wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Background**: I have a set of ggplots (different types) that I would to have displayed next to each other, but they share a common facet.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
 p1 <- mtcars %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(x = wt, y = qsec)) + geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ cyl)

plot(p1)

p2 <- mtcars %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(x = disp, y = qsec)) + geom_smooth() +
  facet_wrap(~ cyl)

plot(p2)
```

**Question**
I would like to have the first plot of p1 (say, above) the first plot of p2, the second plot of p1 above the second plot of p2 and so on... How could I do that? So far my solution is to have p1 and p2 separately, but this is not what I am looking for. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [`patchwork` package](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork)

```
# install.packages("devtools")
# devtools::install_github("thomasp85/patchwork")
library(patchwork)
p1 / p2
```

[image]

Comment: I just tried, but I get "Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘patchwork’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)", any idea how I can still install it?

Comment: @Jean_N You need to install from Github, see my update

Comment: thank you, great! Another question - in the variable that I am using facet wrap on (for my data, not the toy example), I have 9 levels. The overall plot becomes too cluttered, when I display 2x9 plots....Do you have any ideas how I can split the plot so that I display 3 levels only (in the facet wrap), basically achieving to have a layout like the one in the toy example?

Comment: You can set the number of column's and rows in both `facet_wrap` and `facet_grid` with `ncol` or `nrow` as in `facet_wrap(~ cyl, ncol = 3)`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `cowplot` package available on cran.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)

p1 <- mtcars %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(x = wt, y = qsec)) + geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ cyl)

p2 <- mtcars %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(x = disp, y = qsec)) + geom_smooth() +
  facet_wrap(~ cyl)

plot_grid(p1, p2, ncol = 1, align = "v")
```

[image]

I like `cowplot` a lot, but it does change the default theme of `ggplot`.  If you want to change it back, you need to add this: `theme_set(theme_gray())`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ben G ! I would mark your response as an answer if I could too. I knew cowplot from before but I didn't know that it could do this. Cheers!

Comment: What is align="v" doing?
Are there other possibilities?